# close the application buttonListener

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, listener

I am writing a client gui for a server program. The gui and its component buttons are all in a class that extends jframe.

what I need is a button listener that tells the server a message in the event that the client hits the close button on the jframe gui.

I know that

```
  setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

will terminate the application if the button is pressed, but then I can't notify the server before the program terminates.

Answer (score 3):

Use this in your class

```
 WindowAdapter wa = new WindowAdapter()
    {
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we)
        {
            /*inform server*/
        }
    };

    addWindowListener(wa);
```